# Which test to use for small and unequal samples

Tags: sample, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a sample of stroke patients and I want to find the education effect on their performance in a neuropsychological tool. The total sample is n=19. I have divided the sample into 3 groups according to their years of education, so I have 3 groups (1st group: n=5, 2nd: n=5, 3rd: n=9). Shall i do a Mann Whitney U test or a Welch t-test? Or it isn't meaningful to try any test to such a small sample?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that you have divided the patients into groups based on their years of education? Do you mean that you have data on how many years of education each patient has that you then bin into three groups?

Comment: It's probably a rookie mistake and I am considering not divide them. Can I do a regression instead?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Cody. If the effect is strong and consistent, binning the data as you have done will be fine.  But with a small sample it's usually wiser to make the most of the information it supplies.  Your biggest potential problem is that once you have looked at all the data, any new methods you apply will be suspect.  Perhaps you should settle for *exploring* these data rather than applying any hypothesis test.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! What do you mean by exploring?

Comment: Using your data for discovery instead of confirmation, generally by using robust and graphical methods of [exploratory data analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exploratory+data+analysis).